# Is there a way to export all blog posts in Google Sites and import it into Blogger?

Tags: blogger, import, google-classic-sites

I have a Google Site that contains an announcement page. This announcement page is serving like a blog within Google Sites right now, but I would like to migrate it to use Blogger instead. I understand that there is an Import/Export tool in Blogger, but how do I set up the correct XML metadata so that it is suitable for importing from the Google Site?

I thought of manually copying and publishing each post, but it is going to be way too tedious and I want to preserve the date the blog post was published on the Google Site. Is there anyone out there that have tried it before and is willing to help me with this?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this one too. 

fyi, if you do end up doing it manually (tedious but possible), you can set the date for each post to the date that it was originally made. The post-url will get the year/month of the date you enter, and that is the date that will show if you have the date-value displayed in the blog, too.

Comment: You can embed your blogger into Google Sites and unit the two?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra That is one way, but I would like all the posts in the announcements page to be fully migrated to its own Blogger blog.